# When are the cardinalities of 2-factors in a graph equal?

Tags: graph-theory, subgraph

Given a graph $G$, if we can partition the edges into pairwise disjoint subsets of $G$, such that the union of all the subsets is equal to the edgeset of G, then this is a decomposition. If such a partition can be formed from only spanning k-regular graphs, where all the graphs are disjoint, then each of these graphs is a k-factor, and the graph is k-factorizable. If a graph is 2-factorizable, then what conditions are nessasary to make the connected components of each 2-factor the same length?

Related to [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232747/decomposing-a-graph-into-n-cycles/232755#232755)

Comment: All the factors are of equal size by definition.  Do you mean to ask when the components of the factors are of equal size?

Comment: I may just not understand what a factor is, then. Why are they of equal size? I suspect the question you proposed is what I meant to ask, and I just don't know it.

Comment: A 2-factor is a *spanning* 2-regular subgraph.  So if the whole graph has $n$ vertices, a 2-factor has $n$ vertices and $n$ edges.  Perhaps you are just trying to decompose the edge set into cycles?

Comment: You are correct, and this question makes no sense in light of that. However, what is the difference between a two factor and a two factorization? But yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do, I am looking for cycles which are of equal length in the graph.

Comment: A 2-factorization is a partition of the edge set into 2-factors.  Go to Google Scholar and search for "graph cycle decomposition".  There are lots of partial results but no complete answer. You should do such searches before asking a question here.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Yes, I know, but I was googling in the wrong direction- I was looking into the factorization of graphs, not directly into cycle decomposition. Plus, it arose naturally out of the linked question. Nevertheless, thank you, that should help a lot.